# How to set priority on order by in MySQL based on search in columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I am doing simple MySQL query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE col1 LIKE = '%text%' OR col2 LIKE = '%text%'
```

What I need to do, is to sort all the results where the searched text was found in col1 first and after that I need to have results where the searched text was found in col2.

Comment: Why downvote without comment ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a numeric context, boolean values are treated as integers where `0` is `false` and `1` is true, so you could just order by those terms:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     `table`
WHERE    col1 LIKE '%text%' OR col2 LIKE '%text%'
ORDER BY col1 LIKE '%text%' DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

for unsure the proper order you could union (for distinct result) and add  an explict column for order

```
    select col1, col2, col3, .... , coln 
    from (
            SELECT col1, col2, col3, .... , coln , 1 my_order 
            FROM `table` 
            WHERE col1 LIKE = '%text%' 

            UNION 

            SELECT col1, col2, col3, .... , coln , 2  
            FROM `table` 
            WHERE col2 LIKE = '%text%' 
        ) t
    order by my_order
```

or union all for also duplicated  values

```
    select col1, col2, col3, .... , coln 
    from (
            SELECT col1, col2, col3, .... , coln , 1 my_order 
            FROM `table` 
            WHERE col1 LIKE = '%text%' 

            UNION ALL

            SELECT col1, col2, col3, .... , coln , 2  
            FROM `table` 
            WHERE col2 LIKE = '%text%' 
        ) t
    order by my_order
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html), to get the Select results separately, and combine them. Also, `Union` will ensure that duplicates are removed (rows which match both the conditions). If you want the duplicates also, then use `UNION ALL`.

Check the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE col1 LIKE = '%text%' 

UNION 

SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE col2 LIKE = '%text%'
```